# Development Advice: Phonegap or Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

So I need to develop an application that will log a users gps information and transmit it to a cloud database. Once the App is started by the user it will continuously run on the users phone as a background application. My question is because I know based on other SO questions I need a plugin to basically make my app run in the background continuously like this. Is it advisable that I proceed using Phonegap or should I develop entirely in Eclipse? Basically would it be possible to develop something like this entirely in Phonegap (which would be easier for me since this would be my first application) or should I  start down the Eclipse only road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is a framework while Eclipse is an IDE. What you probably mean by "Should I develop with Eclipse?" is "Should I use Android APIs?".

Using Android APIs means you need to know Java. If you know the basics of Java and did some programming with it and if you are fine reading Java docs, using Android APIs directly will provide you most flexibility. You'll probably need to read about life cycles of Android applications but if you are developing applications for Android, this is a must anyway.

PhoneGap is a wrapper for Android APIs and I think such approach is may be feasible for writing UIs but it won't be straight forward for use cases you define in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop professional applications skip phone gap. I have had really bad experience with it. A lot of things aren't documented property, results sometimes vary from the documentation.

It's also inconsistent across platforms. developing a native app saves you the trouble and worry that your app will break in future platform. you also get more controls over the location gps using the native api, a lot of things you won't be able to control on the phone gap layer.

Comment: the lack of high quality free documentation and tutorials is a common frustration.  The operative word is 'free'.  There are also resources of higher quality which are available for a fee.  Phonegap people even have support packages which should take the pain out (http://phonegap.com/support).  I would suggest use of phonegap because it allows you to develop for any platform with only one skillset - html, css, javascript (and of course phonegap).

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap has a background process plugin. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService

further documentation and samples are found at that location.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link for Simple Hello world Phonegap Application, Initial setup to Getting started with PhoneGap in Eclipse for Android

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know some basic Java, just go native. Performance will always be better, and you will have access to the full hardware APIs.

PhoneGap and similar frameworks *might* have good performances, but they will **never** be better than native projects.